# Version Control and Deployment

Tags: git, version-control, e-commerce

I've recently started working for a rather large and well known e-commerce store as a front-end  dev, currently the main one for a specific fascia of ours. What surprised me is that they're not using version control and syncing the dev server and live server is quite the "odd job".

It's not an ideal situation because there's multiple people editing the files on the dev server and the only way to know if we're working on the same file is to ask...

I would like to propose version control and deployment practises but I've not been in that kind of environment before, only heard of it and messed around a little at a personal level. And being the new guy I don't want to over step my mark if you know what I mean.

So, what's the best way to deal with this? I planned on having the files hosted on something like bitbucket. We don't have three servers, just the test server and the live one, so no staging server. I'm just unsure how this kind of workflow goes and how signed off changes are deployed to the live site. Any advice is appreciated.

Apologies if this is in the wrong place... Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a great question for SO in my opinion, but whatever happens stick to your guns! There is *no excuse* for omitting version control in 2014, and your contribution will help the company improve.

Answer (score 0):

Well... put together a business case. Show what it'd do for the company, and how much time and effort would be saved by doing it. Show what it'd cost in time and money to implement (including training if needed). Type it up, add a couple of graphs and present it to your CIO or whoever :)

Good luck, I agree with Chris above - well worth suggesting, even if they don't end up implementing it (though they should!).

Comment: Yeah, that's the plan. To a certain extent at least. What I was wondering though is the technicalities of how this kind of setup works. I've only used git with personal projects so far, as a way to manage my own version history. I'm not too sure how it works with two servers and deploying though... I've been looking for examples on how other e-commerce sites work but no luck :(

Comment: I guess the test server would be the repository host, people would check out from there and work on the code then commit and push back, then when you're ready for testing just check out a local working copy on the testing server and test away. Once that's sorted, check out a copy on live and test there, then roll away?

Bit quick and dirty but it seems the most logical way based on the setup you describe in the OP.